# text field lock in jquery auto-complete - only allow submissions within autocomplete options

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Hei, am looking for help in my code that allows an autocomplete, only within a specified data array. So only data within the auto complete array is allowed to be entered. for example if user has typed iran01 then user wont allow to type 01 because iran01 is not valid . or for example if user type NNN after iran then it wud be iranNNN which is also not valid . Then only iran shud be in textbox which is valid entry . can anyone tell how to do this.

can any one tell how to get this behavior .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                     data = ["iran", "iraq", "Libya", "india"];
                    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete(data)
               });

               $('input#autocomplete').bind('keypress keyup', function(){

                 if ($.inArray($(this).val(), data) == -1){
                    $(this).val('');
                    $("#result").html("No match found!" + $(this).val());
              }

           });

            $('input#autocomplete').result(function (event, data, formatted) {
                $("#result").html(!data ? "No match found!" : "Selected: " + formatted);

            }).keyup(function () {
                $(this).search();

            });

         } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put put a listener on the change event of your input box and then make sure an element has been selected. Check out my answer to this question:

[jquery autocomplete field that REQUIRES a selected value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255551/jquery-autocomplete-field-that-requires-a-selected-value/7259513#7259513)

http://jsfiddle.net/vZeHr/4/

Comment: Ya i checked ur answer but the problem is that i dont want to do empty textbox i want if user type for example America999 then it should nt allow to type 999 after America. America999 is not in list soo thats why i want to lock behavior such as user could not be able to write 999 - and only valid entry stay in textbox .this was my question